# comparing booking and open times

Tags: vb.net

The user inputs a start time and end time of their booking via datetimepickers. I want to be able to make sure that the booking is within the open times of the hall.
I've tried this:

```
MsgBox("start time: " & start_time.value & " End time:" & end_time.value & "")
        If DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "1 " Then
            If start_time.value < "08:00:00" Or end_time.value > "22:30:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "2" Then
            If start_time.value < "08:00:00" Or end_time.value > "22:30:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "3" Then
            If start_time.value < "08:00:00" Or end_time.value > "22:30:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "4" Then
            If start_time.value < "08:00:00" Or end_time.value > "22:30:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "5" Then
            If start_time.value < "08:00:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "6" Then
            If start_time.value < "10:00:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        ElseIf DateTime.Parse(Datetimepicker1.text).DayOfWeek = "7" Then
            If start_time.value < "10:00:00" Then
                errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
            End If
        End If
```

It works for friday, saturday and sunday but not for the other days of the week, which leads me to think it has something to do with the OR operator in those days, but i can quite work out why.

Comment: what type of values are `start_time` and `end_time`? Also you can just use `DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek` instead of calling the `.Parse` method. I'd recommend using a select-case statement for this scenario rather than using if-elseif; greatly increase readability.

Comment: I'm betting Option Strict is not On because `If start_time.value < "10:00:00"` is comparing a DateTime type to a string.  Rather than using DateTime.Parse to get the Dayof Week, `Datetimepicker1.Value` will give you that directly.  Finally, the whole thing could be simplified with an Else or Case Statement

Comment: I'll bet it's actually a timespan value, but that's why I asked in my comment.

Comment: start_time and end_time are inputs from datatimepickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn Option Strict On, you shouldn't be comparing numbers with strings.
Don't repeate your code.
DateTimePicker has a [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property, you do not need to parse the string.

```
Dim startTime, endTime As TimeSpan

startTime = Nothing
endTime = Nothing

Select Case Datetimepicker1.Value.DayOfWeek
    Case DayOfWeek.Monday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
        endTime = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
        endTime = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Wednesday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
        endTime = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Thursday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
        endTime = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Friday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)
    Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
        startTime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)
End Select

If (startTime IsNot Nothing AndAlso Datetimepicker1.Value.TimeOfDay < startTime) Or _
   (endTime IsNot Nothing AndAlso Datetimepicker1.Value.TimeOfDay > endTime) Then
    errors.Enqueue("The booking slot must be within the open hours")
End If
```

The Select Case could easily be in a dictionary and saved as a setting.